Migrate HttpStatus to HttpStatusCode
I have this old code which is used in Spring Boot 2. After update to Spring Boot 3 I get error:
Required type: HttpStatus
Provided: HttpStatusCode

Code:
//old code from
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
HttpStatus statusCode;

if (statusCode == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST){
.....
}

///to
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;


HttpStatusCode statusCode;
if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.valueOf(400){
......
}

What should be the proper way to implement the if(..) check? Just do == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST or use HttpStatusCode.valueOf(400)?

you have to change HttpStatus statusCode to HttpStatusCode in every place

That will work, there are lots of ways to do this.  You can also just compare the value, if (statusCode.value() == 400)  or if (statusCode.isSameCodeAs(statusCode.valueOf(400))).  Also, note that HttpStatusCode permits HttpStatus, so something like this is perfectly legal, HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST

This should do the trick.
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;


HttpStatusCode statusCode;
if (statusCode.isSameCodeAs(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {
......
}

Since HttpStatus is an implementer of HttpStatusCode, this should work fine.
